# i want to create user with custom fields in google firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

If I print conversation in the cloud firebase function , I can see below values of the user,  here, I have changed the userID.  I want the user object with few custom fields for eg : employeeID, age,DOB .

```
user: 
  { userStorage: '{"data":{}}',
    lastSeen: '2018-07-02T08:31:23Z',
    locale: 'en-US',
    userId: myUserID' }
```

i have few question.

•         How to create custom fields for the user?

•         From where it is picking this user details?

•         If I want to create one user with ID “myUserID1”, where I have to create this user?

I think, we can achieve these in amazon cognito.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store specific information about the user, you can put it into the `userStorage` field. This field persists across conversations for the user and doesn't require any additional setup.

```
user:
{
  userStorage: '{"data": { "id": "myUserId" }}',
  lastSeen: '...',
  locale: 'en-US'
}
```

Comment: I want that information, whenever the user login. apart from firebase

Comment: The `userStorage` data is available from the user every time they are interacting with your action. It doesn't use Firebase.